# React: Pass context to dynamically loaded component

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a component that's being loaded dynamically, something like this:

```
LoadScript("path/to/component.bundle.js", () => {
    let comp = getComp()
    ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
           {comp}
    </Provider>, container)
})
```

and in the `component.js`:

```
export function getComp() {
    return <MyComponent />
}
```

However, the `MyComponent` does not have access to the store (which works if not loaded dynamically).  If I change it to:

```
export function getComp() {
    return <Provider store={store}><MyComponent /></Provider>
}
```

then it works, but the store doesn't really seem to be associated (like if there were 2 stores active).  The store is created with createStore from 'react-redux'.

Can anyone tell why MyComponent is not receiving the store/Provider context correctly? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I believe the problem is that I'm using code-splitting and loading both bundles together doesn't work.

In my `webpack.config.js`, I have:

```
entry: {
    admin: './js/index.admin.js',
    kiosk: './js/index.kiosk.js'
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'window',
},
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: 2
    }
}
```

Then, from 'admin' I try to load the 'kiosk' bundle. That's creating 2 stores. Which makes sense since both bundle index files have the following at the top:

```
import store from './store'
```

and `store.js` is defined as:

```
...
export default createStore(reducer, middleware)
```

There's no problem with the reducers since they are all included in both bundles. 
 Note this is not a SPA, but a legacy application that has some components in React.

Comment: since its 2019, maybe you should try https://undux.org :P

Comment: Redux is still one of the better tool you can find, because the community is very large and there are a lot of modules.

Comment: @ Kornflexx, give undux a try then you will change your mind :P

Comment: @deano I'll check it, thanks. I'm pretty new to React. I still need to solve this problem with redux though :-)

Comment: can't you do `return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)` in `getComp()`?

Comment: @codekaizer the component is already connected. I've added info as I believe the problem is with the code-splitting really.

Comment: FYI, for now I've solved it by removing the code splitting for different pages. So not really a solution, but works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than exporting the `createStore` method, you could export a function that either creates the store if it doesn't exist, or returns an already existing instance.

Something like -

```
let instance;

export default getStore = () => {
  if(instance) {
    return instance;
  } else {
    instance = createStore(reducer, middleware);
    return instance;
  }
}
// might need to improve this to eliminate race conditions, 
// or explicitly create the store in this module, 
// and only allow getting an already created store.
```

You might also check if the bundles themselves each have a copy of `redux` in them.  [I'm not sure how multiple entry points handle that].

I had an issue today, where a dynamically loaded module didn't have access to a provider that was clearly an ancestor of the component.
The problem was the dynamically added module had it's own copy of the lib, rather than using the host application's version.